# Truncating file names

Tags: command-line, filename

I am trying to truncate file names down to the last 4 digits (example: 941_S_5193 to become 5193). What would be the most straightforward way to loop this command to apply to roughly 600 files?

Thank you.
-KM

Comment: how do you get the list of concerned files ?

Comment: They are nested in a series of participant files located on my desktop. Example: /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/941_S_5193.

Comment: I have this: `find /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/  -type f -iname  '[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_*' -exec rename 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;`

Comment: Let me ask the format for the names are the same as in"3 numbers_one alphabet_four numbers", if so the code i gave should help

Comment: Just a reminder, be careful of the filenames that could collide during renaming, e.g. ` 941_S_5193` and ` 941_P_5193`  would both  truncate to the same last 4 `5193`.

Answer (score 3):

The `rename` command can do that well enough:

```
# Note, -n flag used for testing only, remove for actual renaming
$ ls
941_P_5191  941_P_5192  941_P_5193  941_P_5194
$ rename -n 's/^(.*)_([0-9]{4})$/$2/'  ./*
./941_P_5191 renamed as 5191
./941_P_5192 renamed as 5192
./941_P_5193 renamed as 5193
./941_P_5194 renamed as 5194
```

You can also do prefix removal in bash and mv within `for` loop:

```
$ for f in ./*; do echo mv "$f" "${f##*_}"; done
mv ./941_P_5191 5191
mv ./941_P_5192 5192
mv ./941_P_5193 5193
mv ./941_P_5194 5194
```

Note: remove `echo` for actual renaming to take place

Comment: FYI "truncating" I've always equated with removing the end of something. So I checked and removing the beginning is called "Clipping": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332906/word-to-describe-removal-of-prefix/332927#332927?newreg=936fc11bd41a46deb363d8cd2ae637d1 (+1 of course :))

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Interesting, never heard "clipping" being used to remove something from beginning, but nice to learn! I think "trim" could be used as well

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thank you for sharing! I never knew that truncate was only removing the end, but I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You gave `941_S_5193` as one file name, but few more would be helpful. I conjured up this `find` command that did it with a sample file called `941_S_5193`:

```
find /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/ -type f -iname '[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_*' -exec rename -n 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;
```

Sample file names:

```
941_S_5194
923_D_5234
941_S_5193
941_S_5134
941_A_0034
941_C_9034
```

Using this command:

```
find /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/ -type f -iname  '[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_*' -exec rename -n 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;
```

Produces these change in filenames:

```
rename(./941_S_5194, ./5194)
rename(./923_D_5234, ./5234)
rename(./941_S_5193, ./5193)
rename(./941_S_5134, ./5134)
rename(./941_A_0034, ./0034)
rename(./941_C_9034, ./9034)
```

Results:

```
0034
5134
5193
5194
5234
9034
```

### Note: Using the '-n' option in rename command lets you see what gets renamed before proceeding with the actual renaming. Remove that option when your ready to rename these files.

Steps to fully appreciate the command are:

1. First of use this `find /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/ -type f -iname '[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_*'` to find the files that will be changed,
2. If steps `(1)` fails then the `regex` does not match the filenames, tweak regex and update your question, else
3. When it comes up as expected now add the `-exec rename -n 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;` part to the command in step (1), so it finds and shows you what gets renamed.

   > `find /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/ -type f -iname  '[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_*' -exec rename -n 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;`
4. When done remove the `-n` option to actually rename these files. Like so:

   - `find /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/ -type f -iname  '[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_*' -exec rename -n 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;`

Comment: The sample files that you listed all follow the correct structure (i.e. 941_S_5193, 928_F_3678 etc. with each one representing its own unique file). However, I haven't been able to get the command to run. No error comes up so I'm not entirely sure which portion isn't working, but I will try tweaking a few more times to see what I can come up with. (Thank you, btw)

Comment: DId you use the `-n` option?

Comment: First of use this `find /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/ -type f -iname` to find the files that will be changed, then when it comes up as expected now add the `-exec rename -n 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;` so it finds and shows you what gets renamed. When done remove the `-n` option to actually rename these files.

Comment: I did try using it with and without the -n command. Still no luck.

Comment: DId you follow the steps I gave and if you did what result did you get from step one

Comment: I just tried the instructions you gave and then got this error after adding step 3: Karins-MBP:~ kmpc$ -exec rename -n 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;
-bash: -exec: command not found

Comment: That's wrong add that part to the one in step one! It should give you `find /users/desktop/km/neuroimage/struct/ -type f -iname  '[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_*' -exec rename -n 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;
`

Comment: When I combine the commands, it gives me this (with and without the -n):    
Karins-MBP:~ kmpc$ find /Users/kmpc/Desktop/ADNIDemo/Functional/ -type f -iname  '[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_*' -exec rename 's/[[:digit:]]*_[[:alpha:]]_//' {} \;
find: rename: No such file or directory
find: rename: No such file or directory
find: rename: No such file or directory
find: rename: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you find the files with the command in step one? That has to return results for the second command to work!

Comment: The files came up fine, it just seems to be breaking down after that point.

Comment: Maybe the files have already been renamed as you have run it with the `-n` option!

Comment: File names are still the same :/

Comment: I did come across another script that might be useful, however, I'm a little stuck on the "sed" portion. Would you by chance know the correct way to edit this:            
for oldfile in /Users/kmpc/Desktop/ADNIDemo/Functional/*
   do
   newfile="$(echo $oldfile | sed 's/-.*//')"  
   mv "$oldfile" "$newfile"
   done

Comment: Change that script to `for oldfile in /Users/kmpc/Desktop/ADNIDemo/Functional/* do newfile="$(echo $oldfile | sed -E 's/[0-9]{3}_[a-zA-Z]_//')" mv "$oldfile" "$newfile" done`

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: SO which script did the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested a loop through the items in the directory using 
`ls | tail -c 5` to list the last 4 digits of each file.

Comment: I need to be able to permanently rename the files, rather than just see the last 4 digits. Also, not all of the end segments begin with 5, so it would be a little less streamlined to specify each beginning digit.